# Slicing Python Lists using list of elements

Tags: python, list

I have the list qf_indexes and I want to slice it into many sublists using another list called used_qf_in:

```
qf_indexes = [  4,  18,  32,  46,  60,  74,  88, 102, 116, 130, 144, 158, 172, 186, 200, 214, 228, 242, 256, 270] 
used_qf_in= [4, 18, 186, 200, 228, 256]
```

such that each sublist starts from one of used_qf_in elements j and contains all the elements in qf_indexes until the element before the one in`j+1`

I tried the following:

```
used_qf_ind =[] 
for j in range(len(used_qf_in)):     
    print(qf_indexes[used_qf_in[j]: used_qf_in[j+1]])     
    used_qf_ind.append(qf_indexes[used_qf_in[j]: used_qf_in[j+1]])
```

I expected to see:

`qf_indexes = [[4],[18,  32,  46,  60,  74,  88, 102, 116, 130, 144, 158, 172],[186], [200, 214, 228, 242], [256, 270]]`

But the result i got when i print inside the loop is :

```
[ 4, 18]
 
[ 32,  46,  60,  74,  88, 102, 116, 130, 144, 158, 172, 186, 200, 214, 228, 242, 256, 270] 
[] 
[] 
[] 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Is the `qf_indexes` always sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `qf_indexes` is sorted you can use [`bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) for more efficient slicing.

```
from bisect import bisect_left
idxs = [bisect_left(qf_indexes, qf) for qf in used_qf_in]
out = [qf_indexes[i:j] for i, j in zip(idxs, idxs[1:])] + [qf_indexes[idxs[-1]:]]

print(out)

[[4],
 [18, 32, 46, 60, 74, 88, 102, 116, 130, 144, 158, 172],
 [186],
 [200, 214],
 [228, 242],
 [256, 270]]
```

Comment: Nice! Much faster than my initial solution.

Comment: @SomeDude What if used_qf_in was not sorted ?

Comment: I measured the speedup: 450x faster than my solution for lengths 10K, 2.5K of the two lists, respectively. Very nice.

Comment: @PierreD thanks for measuring the speeds. makes sense when it uses binary search. :)

Comment: @Accelerator if the used_qf_in wasn't sorted, you can sort the `idxs` first before using them to slice qf_indexes.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC (and assuming that both lists are ordered, and all indices in `used_qf_in` are in `qf_indexes`):

```py
a = [
    qf_indexes[qf_indexes.index(i):qf_indexes.index(j)]
    for i,j in zip(used_qf_in, used_qf_in[1:])
]
>>> a
[[4],
 [18, 32, 46, 60, 74, 88, 102, 116, 130, 144, 158, 172],
 [186],
 [200, 214],
 [228, 242]]
```

**Edit**: [@SomeDude clever idea to use `bisect_left`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75536298/758174) yields a much faster solution. Let's generate some data to measure how much faster:

```py
def gen(n):
    a = np.random.randint(1, 10, n).cumsum()
    b = np.random.choice(a, n // 4, replace=False)
    return a.tolist(), sorted(b)

# example
np.random.seed(0)
a, b = gen(16)
>>> a
[6, 7, 11, 15, 23, 27, 33, 36, 41, 49, 56, 65, 74, 76, 83, 91]

>>> b
[11, 56, 65, 74]
```

Now:

```py
def f0(a, b):
    return [a[a.index(i):a.index(j)] for i,j in zip(b, b[1:])]


from bisect import bisect_left

def f_bisect(a, b):
    idxs = [bisect_left(a, ix) for ix in b]
    return [a[i:j] for i, j in zip(idxs, idxs[1:])] + [b[idxs[-1]:]]

a, b = gen(10_000)

t0 = %timeit -o f0(a, b)
# 869 ms ± 1.29 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

t1 = %timeit -o f_bisect(a, b)
# 1.91 ms ± 326 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

>>> t0.best / tb.best
454.62
```

Over 400x faster for `10_000` elements and 2500 sublists!

Comment: FYI, your original code misses the last _intra_ list.  The last line of `f_bisect` should be `return [a[i:j] for i, j in zip(idxs, idxs[1:])] + [a[idxs[-1]:]]`.  And if you want to go slightly faster by getting `idxs` with `numpy`, you could use `idxs = np.array(a).searchsorted(np.array(b))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can first find the indexes of the numbers with something like this

```
indexes = []
cur_index = 0
for i, n in enumerate(qf_indexes):
    if n == used_qf_in[cur_index]:
        cur_index += 1
        indexes.append(i)
    if cur_index >= len(used_qf_in):
        break
```

or with a comprehension like

```
indexes = [qf_indexes.index(n) for n in used_qf_in]
```

and then create the sub-lists

```
final_list = [qf_indexes[indexes[x]: indexes[x+1]] for x in range(len(used_qf_in)-1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to iterate over the values in the slicing list and use the index method of the sliced list to get the index of each value.

```
qf_indexes = [  4,  18,  32,  46,  60,  74,  88, 102, 116, 130, 144, 158, 172, 186, 200, 214, 228, 242, 256, 270]
used_qf_in = [4, 18, 186, 200, 228, 256]

result = []
start = 0

for value in used_qf_in:
    index = qf_indexes.index(value)
    result.append(qf_indexes[start:index+1])
    start = index+1

# append the remaining elements
if start < len(qf_indexes):
    result.append(qf_indexes[start:])

print(result)
```

> [[4], [18, 32, 46, 60, 74, 88, 102, 116, 130, 144, 158, 172], [186],
> [200, 214, 228, 242], [256, 270]]